# Error importing hydralit: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.report_thread'"

Tags: python, streamlit

I installed Hydralit, but when I try to import I get the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.report_thread'". Interestingly I can import and use hydralit_components.

Versions used:

```
hydralit >=1.0.9
hydralit_components >=1.0.4
streamlit >=0.89
python ==3.8.10
```

Error in full:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hydralit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lorena/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydralit/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hydralit.hydra_app import HydraApp
  File "/home/lorena/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydralit/hydra_app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hydralit.sessionstate import SessionState
  File "/home/lorena/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydralit/sessionstate.py", line 1, in <module>
    import streamlit.report_thread as ReportThread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.report_thread'
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to make my problem go away by replacing

```py
from streamlit.report_thread import add_report_ctx
```

with

```py
from streamlit.script_run_context import add_script_run_ctx
```

(And, of course, replacing uses of `add_report_ctx` with `add_script_run_ctx`.)

I saw, however, on the streamlit discussion page, [a question and answer on this problem](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-streamlit-report-thread/20983), and they said this problem was introduced with 1.4 and to rollback to 1.3. So I am not sure what other problems may occur with my workaround. But I was able to make the import error disappear and a very quick test showed that it works.

Comment: We are facing the exact same error !!, where exactly do we need to replace the add_report_ctx with add_script_run_ctx, in which specific submodule..

Comment: In your code where you are importing. I did not change streamlit code; I changed how I was using the streamlit code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update to Hydralit version 1.0.12, as the issue with Streamlit 1.40 was fixed with the last release. `pip install -U hydralit` should take care of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the user @Phil commented this change worked for me doing it the next way:

I changed the code of the package of ***hydralit*** in the ***sessionstate.py*** script.

If you are using a virtualenv, go to your-virtualenv-name/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/hydralit/sessionstate.py.

If you are not using a virtual environment, find where is your package is installed and do the change there.

In the top part of the **sessionstate.py** file we change:

```
import streamlit
st_ver = int(streamlit.__version__.replace('.',''))

if st_ver < 140:
    import streamlit.report_thread as ReportThread
    from streamlit.server.server import Server
else:
    from streamlit.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx    # Line to change
```

With:

```
import streamlit
st_ver = int(streamlit.__version__.replace('.',''))

if st_ver < 140:
    import streamlit.report_thread as ReportThread
    from streamlit.server.server import Server
else:
    from streamlit.scriptrunner import get_script_run_ctx     # Changed line
```

This solved my problems with the import of hydralit.

Versions of packages:

> streamlit=1.9.0
> HydraLit=1.0.12

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Hydralit has been updated to version 1.0.13, which now supports Streamlit >=1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code in your terminal should work:

```
python3 -m pip install hydralit
```